# Does ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory throw an exception when the directory exists?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-5

According to the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Compression_ZipFile_ExtractToDirectory_System_String_System_String_), the program should throw an `IOException` if the destination directory where the zip file is to be extracted already exists. In addition, the "Remarks" section says, "The destination directory cannot already exist." However,

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("archive.zip", ".\\output");
```

works fine (no exceptions) even if `output` exists as a directory. Something like

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("archive.zip", "\\");
```

also works without exceptions. So, I'm trying to understand why there are no exceptions when the Microsoft Docs clearly suggest there should be one.

Note: I'm running .NET 5.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi According to the Microsoft Docs, there should be an exception so yes, I'm asking why there isn't one.

Comment: @zaggler Those are two separate examples

Comment: @PranavHosangadi the OP asks about the *folder*, not the files. Your fiddle actually proves the OP's point. If you *create* `mytest` before the first `Extract`, the code still works

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right. Here's the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UG0ebI OP's problem is reproducible. (FWIW, that VTC as not reproducible isn't mine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a documentation error. I opened two GitHub issues for this, [one for the source code comments](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53609) and [one for the docs page](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/6788) that's created from them

.NET Core is open source which means we can check the actual source code to see what's going on.

[ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/src/System/IO/Compression/ZipFile.Extract.cs#L188) actually calls the [ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory(ZipArchive, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.extracttodirectory?view=net-5.0) method:

```
public static void ExtractToDirectory(string sourceArchiveFileName, string destinationDirectoryName, Encoding? entryNameEncoding, bool overwriteFiles)
{
    if (sourceArchiveFileName == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sourceArchiveFileName));

    using (ZipArchive archive = Open(sourceArchiveFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Read, entryNameEncoding))
    {
        archive.ExtractToDirectory(destinationDirectoryName, overwriteFiles);
    }
}
```

In [the actual code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/0e557e8fb5b37fbbc57c0a56cae8cfd1ce61b610/src/libraries/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/src/System/IO/Compression/ZipFileExtensions.ZipArchive.Extract.cs#L68) IOException is *not* thrown if the target directory exists, even though the doc site says so:

```
/// <exception cref="IOException">An archive entry?s name is zero-length, contains only whitespace, or contains one or more invalid
/// characters as defined by InvalidPathChars. -or- Extracting an archive entry would have resulted in a destination
/// file that is outside destinationDirectoryName (for example, if the entry name contains parent directory accessors).
/// -or- An archive entry has the same name as an already extracted entry from the same archive.</exception>
public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive source, string destinationDirectoryName, bool overwriteFiles)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    if (destinationDirectoryName == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destinationDirectoryName));

    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in source.Entries)
    {
        entry.ExtractRelativeToDirectory(destinationDirectoryName, overwriteFiles);
    }
}
```

It looks like `learn.microsoft.com` is behind the actual source docs.

For completeness, the [internal ExtractRelativeToDirectory method](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/01b7e73cd378145264a7cb7a09365b41ed42b240/src/libraries/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile/src/System/IO/Compression/ZipFileExtensions.ZipArchiveEntry.Extract.cs#L87) explicitly considers an existing destination folder to be a valid case  :

```
internal static void ExtractRelativeToDirectory(this ZipArchiveEntry source, string destinationDirectoryName, bool overwrite)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    if (destinationDirectoryName == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destinationDirectoryName));

    // Note that this will give us a good DirectoryInfo even if destinationDirectoryName exists:
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
      ...
```

Emphasis on :

> // Note that this will give us a good DirectoryInfo even if destinationDirectoryName exists

Comment: I was suspecting something like this. Thanks for checking. So, if this really is a doc error, is there a way to report it to Microsoft?

Comment: You can do better than that, @bjorn93, there should be an [Edit button in the upper right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Dp8u.png) you can click and edit it yourself.

Comment: @HereticMonkey this only opens the file on Github, it doesn't allow you to actually edit it. It's a good place to open the issues though. I already dd